# Javac complains that can not see jre library classes during compilation

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am trying to compile java classes using javac. The project uses **ByteInputStream** class that is located in **java_version/jre/lib/rt.jar** file(in package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util). javac compilter complains that can't find that class. I tried to include all library classes on during compilation(lib1:lib2:lib3:etc) but still no result.
Here is error message:

```
package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util does not exist 
cannot find symbol  : class ByteInputStream
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using an internal class (i.e. private API)?

Comment: Your code should probably use `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream` instead of `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteInputStream`. Looks like whoever wrote the code accidentally imported the wrong class.

Comment: This is old project. write since 2011. Now I been trying to create Jenkins jobs. I've changed it to ByteArrayInputStream. Hope it won't fail project working lifestyle. Thanks guys.